# Animated randomized background in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, background, android-animation

I'm making a game in androidstudio and I want the background to have a rain effect. I want the amount of drops to be controlled by a variable I set. How would I go about doing this. Maybe create a ton of image views and animate them down the screen (seems very clunky and also process intensive) or is there an external library that could help me out? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use LibGDX and follow this turorial

http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2012/06/tutorial-animated-grass-using-libgdx/

[image]